# Error Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR code 17)) en archivo .msg (Archivo de correo o mail de outlook)

Tags: java, perl

Estoy tratando de realizar un cargue de unos documentos MAIL(archivos de correo exportados a .msg) con un software que maneja mi empresa y este al procesar consume un webservices en java y genera el siguiente error.

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR code 17))
 at [row
col {unknown-source}]: [6
10013]]
```

y al intentar leer este archivo de correo usando perl y utilizando la librería Mail::Exchange::Message me genera el siguiente error al momento de intentar leer este archivo.

```
Multiple properties not implemented at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Mail/Exchange/Property
Container.pm line 192.
```

y este es el codigo que e implementado

```
use Mail::Exchange::Message;
use Mail::Exchange::Message::MessageFlags;
use Mail::Exchange::Recipient;
use Mail::Exchange::Attachment;
use Mail::Exchange::PidTagIDs;
    #listado de archivos mail a procesar
    open(archivo,"D:\\compartida\\repositorio de conocimiento\\1\\entrada.csv");
    #los pongo en un arreglo para recorrerlos y poder cerrar el archivo
    my @rows=<archivo>;
    
    close(archivo);
    foreach $row (@rows){
    
    chomp $row;
    @matrix = split /;/, $row;
    
    #ruta del archivo a tratar
    my $rutaArchivo = $matrix[0];
    #ruta nueva del archivo arreglado
    my $rutaDestino = $matrix[1];
    my $nombre = "";
    #con expresiones regulares obtengo el nombre del archivo de la ruta del mismo
    if($rutaArchivo =~ /.+\\.+\\(.+$)/){
        $nombre = $1;
    }
    elsif($rutaArchivo =~ /.+\/.+\/(.+$)/){
        $nombre = $1;
    }
    
    # print $rutaArchivo."\n";
    
    # creo un nuevo archivo de correo con el contenido del archivo
    my $msg = Mail::Exchange::Message->new($rutaArchivo);
    #codifico el contenido en unicode
    $msg->setUnicode(1);
    #obtendo el contenido del correo
    $msg->setBody(PidTagBody);
    #obtenido los tag de envio del correo
    $msg->setSubject($msg->get(PidTagSubject));
    
    
    

    #borro el archivo mail de la ruta original

    unlink($rutaArchivo);
        #creo archivo mail con correcciones de caracteres en la ruta nueva
        $msg->save($rutaDestino.$nombre);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error de Java indica que se ha encontrado un carácter 17 inesperado. O el archivo no está bien, o está en un formato que el programa Java no entiende.

El error de Perl es parecido. Dice que hay una marca en el archivo que indica que está activada la opción "Propiedades múltiples" en ese archivo, y que esa biblioteca no es capaz de gestionar, por lo que muere inmediatamente.

La solución... complicada... Verificar que el archivo está realmente bien, y usar otras bibliotecas que sí entiendan ese formato.

Otra solución más obvia pero no inmediata es dejar de usar formatos de archivo propietarios, como Exchange. Cada vez que se le cruzan los cables a Microsoft, pues pasan estos problemas. Te dirán que uses sus lenguajes de programación para resolver tu tarea. Podrías intentar pasar el archivo de Exchange a MBox, y así será más fácil de tratar.